# Abnormal behaviour of URL Rewrite Filter

Tags: java, jsf-2, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using [Tuckey URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). In my application, I have the following pages and button:

1. Page `inside.xhtml` which is inside the context of the app: http://example.com/app/inside.xhtml
2. Page `outside.xhtml` which is outside the context of the app: http://example.com/outside.xhtml
3. Page `login.xhtml` at http://example.com/app/login.xhtml
4. A `login button` on `outside.xhtml` page to go to the `login.xhtml` page.
5. Page `profile.xhtml` at http://example.com/app/profile.xhtml
6. A `logout button` on `profile.xhtml` page to go the `inside.xhtml` page.

In the `umlrewrite.xhtml` file, I have the following rule to redirect from `inside.xhtml` to `outside.xhtml`:

```
<rule>
    <note>
        Requests to /app/inside.xhtml will be redirected to ./../../outside.html
    </note>
    <from>/app/inside.xhtml</from>
    <to type="redirect">./../../outside.html</to>
</rule>
```

My logic is that after the user log in at `login.xhtml` page, he will be redirected into the `profile.xhtml` page. What I expect to happen is the following flow:

1. Surf to `outside.xhtml`.
2. Click `login button` to go to `login.xhtml` and log in.
3. Arrive at `profile.xhtml` on success login.
4. Click `logout button` to go to `inside.xhtml`.
5. Get redirected to `outside.xhtml`.

However, what actually happens is:

1. Surf to `outside.xhtml`.
2. Click `login button` to go to `login.xhtml` and log in.
3. **Suddenly get redirected back to `outside.xhtml`.**
4. **Click `login button` to go to `login.xhtml` and log in AGAIN (the app didn't record my login).**
5. Arrive at `profile.xhtml` on success login.
6. Click `logout button` to go to `inside.xhtml`.
7. Get redirected to `outside.xhtml`.

The above situation happen repeatedly if I continue to do step `2` after step `7`.

Without that `<rule>`, I always get redirected to `profile.xhtml` page on success login correctly.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me some advice about this problem.

**UPDATE:**

In my app, to track the `logged in` state, I have a `@SessionScoped` managed bean containing a simple method to record the state:

```
public void recordUserLoggedIn(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession clientSession = request.getSession();
    clientSession.setAttribute("isLogin", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify how you are tracking the "logged in" state.  Are you using a custom cookie?  Relying on the application server's built-in session handling (which is likely also cookie based)?

The most probable cause for your problem is related to how you are tracking the logged in state, and how that state is passed between your various pages & contexts. (Especially when transitioning from logged-in to profile.xhtml.)  Keep in mind that cookies can be path based.

To debug your problem:

- If you are using a browser, then use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network)/[developer-tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) and watch the network tab.  Especially review the various headers that are being set at each step in your flow.
- If not using a browser, then try using a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

I think by watching the HTTP headers during your flow, the underlying problem will become evident.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is that what you need? One thing to note is that without that `rule`, everything was working normally. I think I should have recorded the `logged in` state correctly.

Comment: Your update indicates you are relying on the container's session handling.  My best guess is that your container sets your session cookie to the current path ("/app"). When you then redirect to the parent, the session gets lost until you login again. That's just a guess though. You really need to watch the cookie headers in the HTTP request per my answer.  if easier, you might also try logging the session ID at various stages in your flow. My guess is that it changes even though you don't expect it to.